# Calculating Missing Data Points from the Simplex Tableau

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

I have a few MCQ questions regarding the tableau Simplex Method. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the examples with missing data points. Below are some of the examples that I find weird, and I’m not entirely sure how to solve:

a) For the first example, I have a final Phase $2$ tableau for some problem (P) given by:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
1 & \color{red}\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
x_1&x_2& y_1& y_2&y_3&z_1&z_2&RHS \\  \hline 
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\  
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 4\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 3\\ \hline  
\end{array}$$

The question asks for which $\alpha$ the corresponding basic solution remains optimal?

b) I have both the initial Phase $1$ tableau:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 
x_1&x_2& y_1& y_2&y_3&z_1&z_2&RHS \\  \hline 
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\  
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \color{red} \beta\\ \hline  
-1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 & -3 \\
\end{array}$$

and final Phase $2$ tableau for problem (P):

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
x_1&x_2& y_1& y_2&y_3&z_1&z_2&RHS \\  \hline 
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  \\  
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & \\ \hline  
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 4 & -3 &0 &  \\
\end{array}$$

The question is for which value $\beta$ is the basis in the final tableau degenerate?

Comment: There rare too many questions for one post. Please focus on one.

Comment: I have edited the question. All I want to know is what to look at since it's going to be MCQ and I will be supposed to spend 45-60 seconds per question.

Comment: I  cannot identify the obective function for sure. Is it the first line and what (optimal) value does  it have? Ususally the optimal value value is reached when all coefficients are all non-negative. That means that $\alpha$ should be non-negative as well: $\alpha\geq 0$